# Как вывести список операций сборки openembedded?

Tags: linux, embedded

У меня почему-то не записывается бутменеджер на образ wic. Как выполнить сборку и установку bootx64.efi повторно?

А лучше получить список всех команд bitbake для конкретного образа!